# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '+' found in php

Tags: php, regex

My code is like this

```
preg_match('/b'.'([^+])/'.$country_code.'/',$match)
```

My error is `PHP Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+'`

Actually, what i need is

```
$match = '971-2-53453453';
$country_code = +971
```

I need to search the `971` in the prefix by removing the + in the starting.

Please help me in this.

Comment: I bet your `$document['phone_country_code']` contains `+` sign which gives you an error.

Comment: can you paste a better example ?

Comment: yes... i have + in country_code

Comment: so what you need is match should contain 971 in starting ?

Comment: yes... i need to check + in the phone number. if found , I match with + or remove + and match with the phone number

Answer (score 0):

your slash before the `.$document['phone_country_code']`, what is it ?
escape it if you need a slash